# Installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Using Wubi

Tags: 12.04, wubi

I've had Ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10 on my PC, and just upgraded to 12.04 LTS. I didn't realize that there was capabilities to install it along side with Windows. So now I'm downloading 12.04 with Windows Installer. Should I UNINSTALL the Ubuntu version that's currently partioned? (Windows installer = wubi)

Comment: I tried installing Ubuntu 12.04 Windows Installer, but when it finished downloading, I tried restarting to finish download, as directed, but Ubuntu just hanged and didn't do anything. I had to hard boot it. Could this be caused by me having a version of Ubuntu already partitioned out? I have a x64 bit system by the way. But my main concern is, should I be trying to install the Windows Installer version of 12.04 since I already have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS   installed as a partition? And would you suggest I unstall the partitioned one, before I install the Windows one?

Comment: Where did you get this windows installer? (I have no idea what program you mean).

Comment: Oh, I didn't see this question till now. I got it from the http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer site. There it provides a link to download Windows for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

no, it's easier to just install the new version on the same partition when you install. If you press advanced settings in partition you can change what part of the partition you want to use.

Good luck.

Comment: Hey, thanks Alvar for your response! I would personally prefer to uninstall the current 12.4 LTS version I have, because it doesn't allow for dual boot capability. I have to log off of Windows first, then do a reboot, THEN select Ubuntu in the Grub. That's why I want to go with the Wubi version, because I can run them both side by side, like Mac's Parellels program allows.

Comment: You CANNOT run Wubi "side-by-side" --- you still have to reboot and choose either Windows or Wubi-Ubuntu and stick with it. You can only do what you want with a virtual machine -- try VMWare Player or Virtualbox on Windows, both free.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the "Windows Installer" you refer to is Wubi - if it's not I'm sorry.

As wubi is installed somewhat like a normal programme in Windows it **should be save not to uninstall** your previous Ubuntu versions.

However, since Wubi fiddles with the bootloader you might experience some issues you might not like. Unfortunately I don't know what your bootloader/grub etc. look like.
But since you seem to have gotten along with Windows and Ubuntu side by side in a dual boot setup, you should be fine.

If you do not want your old install(s) of Ubuntu anymore, I suggest you get rid of them after you've made sure 12.04 LTS on Wubi is what you want. But be aware of your bootlader, do not mess it up.

Comment: Thanks Luis, for replying and your helping me. I'm re-downloading Wubi, as we speak(it'll take about an hour to finish). And if I run into the same problem with Ubuntu hanging after reboot, then I can probably safely assume that the cause could be traced to the fact that I have a partitioned out version Ubuntu 12.04 already on my hard drive. I should have clarified with Ubuntu partitioned out, it doesn't allow for dual boot capability, I'll have to shut down Windows side in order to boot the Ubuntu side up. But I'll just uninstall my partition one and will put Wubi on to have dual capability.